# Vue3 - How to invoke a function on App.vue from any components / axios / Pinia

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, pinia

I have a question regarding the vue3 coding structure and wanted to know the best approach to achieve the targetbelow.

**repository**: https://github.com/TraitOtaku/crudapp-vue3

**Office.vue**: To load the main Office view(page), fetch the office data from API and store in the office.js(Pinia)

**OfficeForm.vue**: Template for CRUD form for Office data. Clicking OK button will update the data. **I also wanted to trigger the popup(toast) if Axios returns success.**

**office.js**:Pinia file that stores office data fetched by Axios

https://github.com/TraitOtaku/crudapp-vue3/blob/master/src/views/admin-views/team/Office.vue
https://github.com/TraitOtaku/crudapp-vue3/blob/master/src/components/layout-ui/form/member/OfficeForm.vue

I use this PrimeVue UI library (https://primefaces.org/primevue/toast)
and wanted to invoke the Toast popups from any components.

Target:
I have this  toast component from PrimeVue UI library on the `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <LayoutView></LayoutView>

  <!-- POP UP MESSAGE -->
  <Toast position="bottom-left" />
</template>
```

in App.vue `<script setup>` :

```
const showSuccess = () => {
  toast.add({
    severity: "success",
    summary: "Success Message",
    detail: "Message Content",
    life: 3000,
  });
};

const showError = () => {
  toast.add({
    severity: "warn",
    summary: "Error Occurred",
    detail: "Something went wrong",
    life: 3000,
  });
};
```

Question:
**How can I invoke the showSuccess() and showError() from any child components?**

My idea 1:
Use Provide/Inject and send the showSuccess() and showError() to Pinia store and invoke each function after the Axios response.
-> Seems to be difficult to implement the inject() in .js file.

My idea 2:
Use $root$emit to invoke the App.vue's showSuccess() and showError().
-> I have no idea how to receive the emmited $root$emit from App.vue file.

My idea 3:
Store the value (i.g. createdData = ref(0) ) and createdData++ when Axios returns success.
create a watcher in the App.vue file and invoke showSuccess() when createdData.value changes

Note: I just don't want to repeat this  component everywhere in the Vue application.

Please advise.
Thank you!

Comment: showSuccess, etc, can just be Pinia actions. It's intended for global logic. " Seems to be difficult to implement the inject() in .js file" - why? The code where inject() is called should be executed inside Vue instance that has respective provide(), this is the only thing that matters. Btw inject is totally unnecessary for primevue toast, you can check its implementation.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I needed the hint from you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply I added the toast function and it worked!

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref, toRaw, inject } from "vue";
import EventService from "@/plugins/EventService";
import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";

export const useOfficeStore = defineStore("office", () => {
  const toast = useToast();
  const data = ref(null);

  const getData = () => {
    EventService.getOffice()
      .then((response) => {
        data.value = response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("data:" + error);
        toast.add({
          severity: "warn",
          summary: "Network Error",
          detail: "Database connection error",
          life: 3000,
        });
      });
  };
  getData();

  const updateData = (formState, id) => {
    EventService.updateOffice(id, toRaw(formState))
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Office Updated" + response.data);
        getData();
        toast.add({
          severity: "info",
          summary: "Data Created",
          detail: "Office Data was successfully updated",
          life: 3000,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        getData();
        toast.add({
          severity: "error",
          summary: "Error Occurred",
          detail: "Data was not updated",
          life: 3000,
        });
      });
  };

  return {
    data,
    getData,
    updateData,
  };
});
```